# How to toggle between a play and pause button?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Essentially, I would like to know the best way to toggle between two img or div on a user click. So, first the play image is visible and when user clicks, play image is hidden and pause image is shown. When user clicks pause image, pause image is hidden and play image is shown.

I tried using an ng-show but I could only figure out how to show both images without hiding the other. So, a play image would be next to the pause image, which is not ideal.

Thanks in advance :)

Code I have tried that does not work:

HTML

```
<button ng-click="changeStatus" ng-show="checkStatus">Play</button>
<button ng-click="changeStatusAgain" ng-hide="checkStatus">Pause</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeStatus=function(){
    $scope.checkStatus = false;
}

$scope.changeStatusAgain=function(){
    $scope.checkStatus = true;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n8nnwtte/

Comment: Sounds like you need to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You should post an MVCE of your attempt, what it does wrong/undesirable behavior, and what you'd like it to do. Additionally questions that follow the "what is the best way to X" are off-topic, so you could consider narrowing that down as well when you rewrite.

Comment: Got it! I will do a quick rewrite with all the code I tried. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the same expression for both and negate it according to your logic.

**HTML**

```
 <button class="play" ng-show="!song.playing" ng-click="song.togglePlay()">
 <button class="pause" ng-show="song.playing" ng-click="song.togglePlay()">
```

**JS**

```
var $scope.song = {
    playing: false, // Set the initial state

    togglePlay: function() {
         $scope.song.playing = !$scope.song.playing; // This would alternate the state each time

         // Do something with the song
        if ($scope.song.playing) { /*..*/ }  else { /*..*/ }
    }
};
```

This assumes you have a `song` object defined in your scope and that it has a boolean property called `playing`. So if `song.playing` is falsy we show the play button and if it's truthy we show the pause button.

The `togglePlay()` method defined can then be used to alternate the state of `song.playing` in addition to its role of actually controlling the playback.

Comment: Your solution is great but a little to sophisticated for my problem. I incorporated a boolean property based on the ng-click but for whatever reason, it does not switch when clicked. I have added code above to show you what I have written. :)

Comment: @MehdiN Your updated code seems to be valid albeit confusing. It could be that something is missing in your original code that makes it fail. I've updated my example using the same logic suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Toggle (Play/Pause) Sound on Click Event of DOM Element

his post shows how to toggle (play/pause) sound by JavaScript manipulation of onclick event of a DOM element. Browser support of HTML5 audio tag is a must in this example.

https://siongui.github.io/code/javascript-sound/toggle.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Toggle (Play/Pause) Sound on Click Event of DOM Element</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="player" type="button"
  onclick="javascript:toggleSound();">
  Click to Toggle Sound
</button>
<audio id="audio">
  <source src="Wat_Metta_Buddha_Qualities.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleSound() {
  var audioElem = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (audioElem.paused)
    audioElem.play();
  else
    audioElem.pause();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```